# Xcode 5 on Mavericks cant find libraries (expat, zlib, pthread, iconv)

Tags: xcode5, wxwidgets, osx-mavericks

When trying to build a wxwidgets project, using XCode 5.0.2, the linker gets

```
-lexpat -lz -lpthread -liconv
```

but it complains it cannot find the libraries:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lexpat
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lexpat is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lz
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lz is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lpthread
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lpthread is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -liconv
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -liconv is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

The libraries (or at least the dynamic version of them) seem all to be installed - if I choose the project target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries, I can add, for instance, libz.dylib; yet the error persist.

As for expat, I've managed to solve it by adding /usr with recursive flag to the *Library Search Path*.

Can anyone shed some light on this?